# Unable to connect to GIT repository from one of the linux server

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ssh, alm

When I try to clone the repository in Linux machine I am facing the below issue

```
-bash-4.1$ git clone
 ssh://xxxxx@alm.oraclecorp.com:2222/epm_pbcs_15318/pbcs.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/xxxx/testgit/pbcs/.git/

Permission denied (keyboard-interactive,publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Note:- I have added public ssh key in the repository

I have generated a key in my Linux machine using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@gmail.com"
```

and later on, copied the public key to alm where the GIT is hosted.

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAwVM4haHIEOk6P7+h4xEDyZBrGjSLx53jNFE1AqMNWnPKWwxpGX5w4l/B0WJpP7G9gLJaZPw9loSEDDr3mGx5bRi3D8k6EFgFMpctALJlKTHFW1x47A1Z+0h2GZUvL5WZj1ZXicvpbHRxX5B+FB8s+b2d3uvwVVl26lIK3f6K2iUiRePlUH/1TPBTk/kzxvDBZQCRQKxM4Zb13S7b9WJcxt85g3+jCIebDbAaswUmIeWicM+BREmcP75ZV6ZEF1cBB54TvMrygsTzJacQS6/IsobOaZpWM7iVXTnEGjFh8iKCA5VacMMEt+QR8kc/CGOm1ujcNFbK6hikp2CpSOo4wQ== email@gmail.co
```

Please help me if there is any way to fix it

Comment: Is that the entire pub key you added? bc there is an 'm' missing at the very end

Comment: @harmonica141 That doesn't matter — the last part of the key is a *comment*, it can be anything. Usually it's the ID/name of the key; email is a kind of ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not using your private key to connect to that repository.

The easiest way to do it is by adding the following lines to either `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, please be careful and add the lines at the beggining of the file, `*` configuration must be at the end of the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (if you use this file for configuration):

```
Host alm.oraclecorp.com
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    IdentityFile YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_LOCATION
    Port 2222
    User YOUR_USER
```

**REMEMBER TO EDIT `YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_LOCATION` AND `YOUR_USER` with your data**

Let me know if this worked.

BR

Comment: could you run `git config core.sshCommand "ssh" -vvv` in your git folder and attach log output?

Comment: repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 sshCommand = ssh

Comment: the issue is resolved after placing the ssh keys under scratch/user/.ssh instead of placing it in home/user/.ssh . Could you please let me know what could be the possible reason

Comment: The problem was related to your SSH connection, you we trying to download a repository without your private key and server rejected your connection...

Comment: I could see a private key bu still I was facing the issue